# Syntax for referencing sub-buckets in Vega

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega

I have an Elasticsearch (6.2) query that returns the following JSON:

```
"aggregations": {
  "per_buyer": {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
    "buckets": [
      {
        "key": "Example-buyer",
        "doc_count": 45,
        "per_cart": {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count": 6,
          "buckets": [
            {
              "key": "397105FB",
              "doc_count": 8,
              "net": {
                "value": 10
} } ] } } ] } }
```

What is the correct syntax for the vega "format" field to display data per "per_cart" bucket? Anything deeper than `aggregations.per_buyer.buckets` returns the error `_.aggregations.per_buyer.buckets.per_cart is undefined` . `VEGA_DEBUG.view.data` shows that some `aggregations.per_buyer.buckets` have a "per_cart" object, which in turn have buckets. ( Filtering so that all buckets have per_cart objects does not change anything. )

I previously asked this question without success on the [Elastic forums](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/format-for-multi-level-aggregation-in-vega/127193).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry missed the request in the discuss forum.  Cross-posting my answer here:

@Steven_Ensslen your `format` must be `aggregations.per_buyer.buckets`, simply because that's the list of data that you need.  Each data element in that bucket may contain a sub-list of buckets which you have to access from Vega itself.   Now, if the sub-list will always have just a single bucket (e.g. if you are summing-up the total per main bucket), you can access it either directly from a mark, e.g. `datum.per_cart.buckets[0].net.value`, or you can create a formula transform that would copy that value into a top level field, e.g. `{type:'formula', as:'net_value', expr: 'datum.per_cart.buckets[0].net.value'}`, and use the `net_value` field in the mark.  If on the other hand you have multiple items in the sub-list, you could use the `flatten` transform to flatten out the sub-buckets into a non-hierarchical list of items, and then use various transformations to get the data into the format you need.

P.S. "flatten" transform may not be available until 6.3 or 6.4.